# Cases of different pronunciation and word meaning in American and British English and its influence on the sense of humour

Tags: word-meaning, pronunciation

Spellings and pronunciations of some words in American and British versions of the English language sometimes don't coincide.Also, these versions have different meanings of some words( like the most well-known pants vs trousers, rubber vs condom, sidewalk vs pavement).So probably because of these differences American and British may misunderstand each other.
    I'm curious to know if there are some jokes where the tricky words of this kind are used?I mean if there are any jokes which belong to the British, but can't be understood by Americans, or belong to Americans but can't be understood by the British only because of different word meaning or different pronunciation, but could be understood by them if there were no these differences between the American and British versions?

Comment: In a collection of humorous musical definitions, I've seen _baroque_ illustrated with a drawing of a man in a full-bottomed wig turning his empty pockets inside-out. A British person can understand the pun, but it doesn't work so well for us because we pronounce _baroque_ to rhyme with _stock_ rather than _stoke_.

Comment: Many Brits find it funny that there are lots of people in the USA whose surname is Wank.

Comment: [This incredibly long joke](https://natethesnake.com/) was an absolute waste of time for me (Br.) as it relies on an American pronunciation.  However I think "can't be understood" is putting it a bit strongly.  I understand what the joke is meant to be, once I think about it and mentally translate to Am.Eng - it's just that by the time I do that, it's not funny.

Comment: That is a really stupid joke. We in Britain have been exposed to Americans saying 'levver' since before Davy Crockett was on the TV, but I don't think the Yanks know so much about us.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is trivial and it encourages a neverending list of example jokes as answers.